# Ubuntu - run OpenVPN client from network-manager as unprivileged user

Tags: openvpn

I am trying to connect to a VPN using OpenVPN. The authentication is successful (I can see that when I run `openvpn` from the command line) but then my user doesn't have enough privileges to run ifconfig and other configurations. If I run as root via the command line the VPN connects successfully.

I have no problem typing my user's password to run the VPN, but unfortunately, the network manager applet does not prompt me for a password. Instead, the connection simply fails. I want to use the network manager for this, not the command line. Any thoughts?